# How can I pass data from app extension to host application and upload it Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios-app-extension, appgroups

I am using an app extension to allow users to save webpage URLs to my app so I can display them in a `UITableView`. I have created the action extension but I'm especially struggling with uploading the data to Firebase. I know it is not performance-friendly to upload to Firebase from the Action Extension, so I want to send the URL back to the host app to be processed. The one question I have though -- how can I notify the host app that a new URL has been retrieved using the action extension so I can upload it to Firebase?

I was planning on using delegates and protocols, but there is no way to use them in app groups. I also have looked into [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole), but I am not sure how that would work with my app's needs.

How can I notify the host app that a URL has been retrieved using the action extension so I can upload it to Firebase?

Comment: "I know it is not performance-friendly to upload to Firebase from the Action Extension" - Did you try it?

Comment: @Cyberbeni No, that is just what I have heard. I'm sorry, I should not say "I know" as I haven't tested it myself. I just am unsure as to how I can get users authenticated in Firebase if they are technically using a different app so I was struggling with that too.